# Annotations in parameters IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to set annotation in IntelliJ IDEA in a way that annotations are on their own line EXCEPT when annotating a parameter?

Example of what I mean and how I want it..

```
@Annotation
@Annotation
String variable; 

@Annotation
public void doMethod(@Annotation String x, @Annotation int y){

}
```

But everything in the settings seems to set it so i can only have one or the other.

Here are my settings [image]

With how I have my settings now my code comes out like this...

```
@Annotation
@Annotation
String variable;

@Annotation
public void doMethod(
        @Annotation
        final String x,
        @Annotation
        final int y) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My settings are as follows, which appears to give you the annotation style you're looking for:

- Parameter annotations: **Chop down if long**
- Local variable annotations: **Do not wrap**
- Annotation parameters: **Chop down if long**

  - Align when multiline: **Yes**